# react-native ScrollView for images is outputs only single image

Tags: react-native, scrollview

scrollview is not taking images properly ,outputs only one image in my code ...

```
<ScrollView scrollEventThrottle={16}> 
    <View style={styles.scrollcontainer}>
        <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/banner.png')} style={{height:120,width:120,resizeMode:'cover'}}/>
            <Image source={require('../assets/banner.png')} style={{height:120,width:120,resizeMode:'cover'}}/>
            <Image source={require('../assets/banner.png')} style={{height:120,width:120,resizeMode:'cover'}}/>
            <Image source={require('../assets/banner.png')} style={{height:120,width:120,resizeMode:'cover'}}/>
        </ScrollView>                           
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the reproduction of your issue and it seems working as expected.

https://snack.expo.io/SJMX0BQn4 Check this snack

Please also share styles.scrollcontainer details. It may be related to styling of view